# Can Luffy's cut wounds seal like rubber?

Tags: one-piece

Since Luffy's body is made of rubber, can small cut wounds/gashes seal like rubber in the real world would normally do? Or do they heal like normal skin?

Answer (score 1):

SPOILER ALERT!

Not actually rubber. Luffy's devil fruit is not really the Gum-Gum Fruit, but

> the Hito-Hito (i.e. Human-Human) fruit model Nika, which gives him the ability to manipulate his body however he can imagine, and upon awakening, also the surroundings.

So, this question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Luffy  doesn't have the ability to heal himself immediately, we can see him wrapped up in bandages pretty much after every hard fight he gets into. So he can only heal like a normal person

Answer (score 0):

As terrible of an idea it would be for him to heal like rubber since it doesn't heal at all, Luffy heals like a human. Remember, Luffy is like rubber, He isn't rubber though. He's still skin and bones. If he was like rubber, Luffy would not sink in water. But he still has the density of a human. Or maybe it's the fact that he turns completely human when touched by rubber.

Answer (score 0):

I think he could with the help from:

> Mansherry, who ate the Chiyu Chiyu no Mi, a Paramecia-type Devil Fruit that gives her the ability to instantly heal any living being's injury.